# $.ajax POST works but $.post does not

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I'm doing a simple post of a form using jquery. The problem is the $.ajax with POST is working but $.post is not. Look at the code below:

```
 $.post(
        {
            url: url,
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                alert('startline posted');
            }                
        });
```

And the working edition

```
            $.ajax(
        {
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                alert('startline posted');
            },
            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error '" + jqXhr.status + "' (textStatus: '" + textStatus + "', errorThrown: '" + errorThrown + "')");
            }
        });
```

Been debugging the $.post example until I just wanted to try out the $.ajax edition to get an error msg. But unfortunatly it just worked :)

How are the two methods different?

Comment: In your debugging was there a difference between the requests created by each method?  Watching the requests in something like the Net tab in FireBug may reveal more information.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter format for [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) is `url, data, callback, datatype`.  The parameter for [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) is `url, options` or just `options` as you are using.  In other words, the formatting on your `$.post` call is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks, How could I miss that. You get the answer as you explained why.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.post( url, form.serialize())
    .success( function (result) {
                alert('startline posted');
});
```

try it

Answer (score 1):

`$.post` takes multiple arguments, not one object like `$.ajax`.  try it like this:

```
$.post(url, form.serialize(),  function (result) {
                alert('startline posted');
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you use [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
$.post('url/here.php', {

    data: form.serialize()
}, function(result) {

    alert('startline posted');
});
```